# MongoDB Multiple Verbatim into single field for comments

Tags: mongodb

I have data such as:

```
{"ID" : "334", "Q1": "aaaaaaa", "Q2": "bbbbbbbbb"},
{"ID" : "335", "Q1": "cccccc", "Q2": "ddddddd"},
```

and want to combine fields to result:

```
{"ID" : "334", "Q": "Q1", "Comment": "aaaaaaaa"},
{"ID" : "334", "Q": "Q2", "Comment": "bbbbbbbb"},
{"ID" : "335", "Q": "Q1", "Comment": "cccccccc"},
{"ID" : "334", "Q": "Q2", "Comment": "dddddddd"}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/ Also, isn't it ironic that you use Mongo and try to produce normalized (SQL-like) data out of it? Maybe you should re-assess your database choice?

Comment: are you going to store results in same collection or there is a chance to save data in new one and  then rename?

Comment: No, only for running live aggregate queries. Thanks, got solution, will show below.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('test1').aggregate(
[
{
  $project: {
    _id: false,
    id: "$ID", 
    comment : [{"id": {"$literal":"Q1"} , "text": "$Q1"}, {"id":  {"$literal":"Q2"}, "text": "$Q2"}]  }  },
{
 $unwind : "$comment"   
},
{$match : {comment.text : {$ne: null}}   
}
]
)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".